# Finding the right exception in python

Tags: python

```
try:
#'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop'
#'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
except TypeError:
    #this code should run if any of the two errors happens, but doesn't
    #right now it doesn't OFC
except Exception as e:
    input(e)
```

Here is a list of all the exceptions in python
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/pythons-built-in-exceptions

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve and in any case asking for recommendation to find software, libraries, etc. is off-topic. Check [ask].

Comment: If you remove the try/except from your code the traceback will tell you the exact exception

Comment: The question is vague and it is not clear what you're trying to do...

Comment: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop'` is an AttributeError, not TypeError.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To determine, you can use `sys.exc_info`.

```py
from sys import exc_info

try:
    # raise exception
except:
    print(exc_info()[0])
```